# Show/hide dynamic td by select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I've been looking for solution in other posts but I didn't find and I couldn't understand other solutions.

I want to show a td or other depending of select value. This td's are inside a loop that create dynamical each row of the table with a key.

Here is the part of my code I need to change. The first td is the select that choose what to show. The others td must be shown depending of the first select.

```
<%-- Empresa--%>
    <td>
        <% String onchange = "javascript:buttonUpdateVisibility(" + key + ",this);"; %>
        <select name="<%=contratoTrabajadorTipo%>" onchange="<%=onchange%>">
            <option value="<%=ContratoTrabajador.TIPO_CONTRATO%>"><bean:message key="contrata"/></option>
            <option value="<%=ContratoTrabajador.TIPO_SUBCONTRATA%>"><bean:message key="subcontrata"/></option>
        </select> 
    </td>
    <%-- Subcontrata --%>
    <td>
        <%  
            String keyContrata = key + "_contrata";
            String keySubcontrata = key + "_subcontrata";   
        %>
        <span id="<%=keyContrata%>" style="display: none;"><bean:write name="contratoEntregaForm" property="nombreEmpresa" /></span>
        <html:select styleId="<%=keySubcontrata%>" property="<%=contratoTrabajadorSubcontrata%>" styleClass="campoSelect">
            <html:options collection="<%=WebConstants.LISTA_EMPRESAS_KEY%>" labelProperty="nombreComercial" property="idEmpresa"/>
        </html:select>
    </td>
```

I was trying to create a javascript function for update visibility buf I don't know how to do it.

```
function buttonUpdateVisibility(key,sel){
    if(sel.value == 'C'){
        document.getElementById(key+"_contrata").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(key+"_subcontrata").style.display = "block";
    } else if(sel.value == 'S'){
        document.getElementById(key+"_contrata").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(key+"_subcontrata").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Maybe it's possible to make it with jquery but I don't know much about the language. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
function buttonUpdateVisibility(key,sel){
    if(sel.value == 'C'){
        $("#"+key+"_contrata").hide();
        $("#"+key+"_subcontrata").show();
    } else if(sel.value == 'S'){
        $("#"+key+"_contrata").show();
        $("#"+key+"_subcontrata").hide();
    }
}
```

And call function like

```
onchange="javascript:buttonUpdateVisibility('<%=key%>',this); ">
// Use quotes for key ----------------------^--------^
```

Comment: Thanks it did work, I only had to change $("#"+key+"_contrata").hide(); for $("#"+key.id+"_contrata").hide();